# For $Y\sim Bern(\pi)$, why is $log(\mathbb{1}(Y=1)\pi + \mathbb{1}(Y=0)(1-\pi)) =\mathbb{1}(Y=1)\log\pi + \mathbb{1}(Y=0)\log(1-\pi)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $Y$ is a random Bernoulli random variable with success probability $\pi$. I am wondering why is it that:

$$
\log\left[\mathbb{1}(Y=1)\pi + \mathbb{1}(Y=0)(1-\pi)\right] = \mathbb{1}(Y=1)\log\pi + \mathbb{1}(Y=0)\log(1-\pi)
$$

In general, the logarithm of a sum is NOT the sum of the logarithms, but here it appears to be the case.

I am able to understand why by taking it case by case, i.e., let $Y=1$, then let $Y=0$.

My question is, is there a more formal or deeper way of understanding what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: "Success probability" $\pi$ ? Like $\pi \approx 3.141592$ ? Also the LHS is supposed to be $\log \mathbb{E}[Y]$ ?

Comment: I think your problem is with your definition of $1(Y=1)$ and $1(Y=0)$. What exactly do you mean by that? If you mean that when $Y=1$, $1(Y=1) = 1$ and $1(Y=0) = 0$ then your formula works, but it would also work with any other function than the log, and any value other than $\pi$. In short, it would be kind of a useless formula. And anyways that wouldn't be a very orthodox notation in my sense. If you meant something else please explain.

Comment: The success probability is an arbitrary parameter such that $\pi \in (0,1)$. I mean that $\mathbb{1}(Y=1)$ is the indicator function of $Y=1$, in that it is $1$ if $Y=1$ and $0$ if $Y=0$. Thanks

Comment: Usually, the indicator function is written $\Bbb{1}_{\{Y=1\}}$ or $\chi_{\{Y=1\}}$.

Comment: What you have mentioned as the case by case statement, is all there is to it! Since $Y$ can take either $0$ or $1$, never both.

Comment: Because $$\log\left[1\cdot\pi + 0\cdot(1-\pi)\right] = \log\pi=1\cdot\log\pi + 0\cdot\log(1-\pi)$$ and $$\log\left[0\cdot\pi + 1\cdot(1-\pi)\right] = \log(1-\pi)=0\cdot\log\pi + 1\cdot\log(1-\pi)$$